# My Ubuntu 14.04LTS machine randomly freezes, could anyone tell me the possible reason?

Tags: 14.04

I use a Dell inspiron 5558 system with ubuntu 14.04 LTS and win 10 dual boot. At times, when using ubuntu, the screen freezes. It is quite random in occurence. 
For example, once I was watching a video and was trying to switch from full screen to normal mode, the screen suddenly froze but the sound was unaffected. 
What could be the probable reason for this kind of a problem?

Comment: Do you have an NVIDIA card, and do you have the proprietary drivers installed?

Comment: i have an nvidia card but i don't have any drivers installed on ubuntu

Comment: Ah. Open the Additional Drivers app by searching for it and install the newest NVIDIA proprietary option there. Install it and reboot and see if it helps.

Comment: When this happens is your keyboard also ignored ? ... to check hit ctrl-alt-t which if keyboard is working will open up a terminal window ... if this also fails then hit ctrl-alt-F2 which will take you to a console window login prompt ... Does it ? If so then to return back hit ctrl-alt-F7 at which point your mouse and keyboard should be working fine again

If all of the above is true I also suffered from same issue which in my case was only triggered if I used the laptop trackpad .. avoiding trackpad usage did avoid this hanging issue .. On same machine w/ubuntu 16.04 this problem disappeared

Comment: On pressing ctrl+alt+F2 and going back via ctrl+alt+F7 isn't helping..

Comment: After installing the newest nvidia driver, I'm now being shown a black screen on startup (in place of the password prompt)